# Pivot report in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, pivot, pivot-table

I have a summary table in SQL Server with my daily production details as follows.

Table name: `ProductionDet`

Structure:

```
id          int (primary key, auto increment)
date        date
tran_type   varchar(1) (this field has 'I' for Issue, 'R' for Receive.)
emp_id      int
Proc_id     int
Pcs         int
weight      decimal(10,3)
```

when some employee do some production, my application insert or updated that pcs, weight in this table for that date. This table has unique key with date, tran_type, emp_id and Proc_id.

Now I want to create pivot report with opening and closing details based on this table. this report will be generate on various types of grouping options. e.g. monthly, daily, quarterly, yearly, employee wise, process wise. opening and closing value we have to calculate based on selected date.
here is the sample output :

Result 1 (Daily Report):

```
                            emp_id_1            
            ________________________________________
                  Opening   Receive Issued  Closing
            ----------------------------------------
01/04/13    Pcs   5         5       2       8
            Wgt   5.2458    5.142   2.222   8.1658
            ----------------------------------------
02/04/13    Pcs   8         3       7       4
            Wgt   8.1658    3.547   7.888   3.8248
```

Result 2 (Monthly Report):

```
                    emp_id_1            
            ________________________________________
                  Opening   Receive Issued  Closing
            ----------------------------------------
Apr '13     Pcs   5         8        9      4
            Wgt   5.2458    8.689   10.11   3.8248
```

I am using SQL Server 2008. Is there option in SQL Server 2012/2013? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I have used in similar reports when I needed to calulate the summary up until a date of transactions and I hope I understand the question right.

- Group the data per date and sum the delta.
- Join the result with itself where you join all deltas before the date.

**Step #1**
Group all data per date. If you would like filters on employer etc, add that in this query.

```
select *,ReceivedPcs - IssuedPcs PcsDelta,ReceivedWgt - IssuedWgt WgtDelta, row_number() over (order by date) RowNo 
into #ReportData1
from 
(
    select      Date, 
        sum(case when tran_type = 'I' then pcs else 0 end) IssuedPcs, 
        sum(case when tran_type = 'R' then pcs else 0 end) ReceivedPcs, 
        sum(case when tran_type = 'I' then [weight] else 0 end) IssuedWgt, 
        sum(case when tran_type = 'I' then [weight] else 0 end) ReceivedWgt
        from ProductionDet
    group by date
) s
```

**Step #2**
Join the result with itself and use one set for the "today" values (a) and one to sum all deltas before today (s).

```
select a.Date, a.IssuedPcs, a.ReceivedPcs,
       a.IssuedWgt, a.ReceivedWgt, 
       a.WgtDelta, a.PcsDelta, 
       sum(isnull(s.WgtDelta,0)) OpeningWgt , 
       sum(isnull(s.PcsDelta,0)) OpeningPcs 
from #ReportData1 a
left outer join #ReportData1 s on s.Date < a.Date
group by a.Date, a.IssuedPcs, a.ReceivedPcs, a.IssuedWgt, a.ReceivedWgt, a.WgtDelta, a.PcsDelta
```

There you have the data for the daily report. You can apply the same logic for the monthly report, just grouping on `DatePart(year,date)*100 + DatePart(month,date)` or any other way of getting the month.

I belive the formatting should not be an issue.

I think there is a simpler way in SQL 2012 as there is a function with a similar syntax to Row_number, but I am going to explain how do do this witout that function.